# Временная ссылка на видеофайл для встраивания в плеер средствами php

Tags: php, файлы, видео, http-заголовки

Для защиты видео файлов от встраивания/скачивания на другие сайты используют временные ссылки... Для того чтобы отдавать файл на скачивание прописываются заголовки стрима вроде вот такого варианта:

```
function file_download($file) {
if (file_exists($file)) {
if (ob_get_level()) {
  ob_end_clean();
}

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
readfile($file);
return [
    'status' => 'success',
    'message' => 'Файл успешно отдан'
];
}else {
return [
    'status' => 'error',
    'message' => 'Файл не найден'
  ];
}
 }

$vrem_ident = $_GET['file'];
//здесь находим какому пути к файлу соответствует временная ссылка
//$file - путь к файлу

file_download($file);
```

[Код взят вот отсюда](https://unetway.com/blog/otdaem-fajly-effektivno-s-pomosu-php)

Если вставить как есть, то видео проигрывается, но нельзя перематывать. Делается это вроде заголовком Content-range? Если так, то как его правильно прописать?

Как правильно прописать заголовки, изменить код чтобы можно было вставлять временную ссылку в плеер и тот воспроизводил видео как будто в него вставили путь к реальному файлу?

Как такое организовать, если файлы видео будут не на том сервере на котором данный скрипт(например отдельный сервер для хранения видео или чтобы проксировать видео из Юуба или Вконтакте)?  В таком случае просто вставляется ссылка, или возникнут какие-то трудности?

Comment: Слишком много вопросов в одном, рекомендую разбить на отдельные.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov  Ответьте про то как отдавать видео php файлом, чтобы плеер считал реальным файлом. Остальное это уточнения, которые не обязательны, и лишь помогут, как мне кажется, заставить прочитавшего понять ответ в полной мере, а не просто скопипастить код.

Comment: Вот [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38633165/streaming-video-with-php-html5) для PHP, надеюсь достаточно подробный, с англоязычного SO.